# Searching a value in the linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, insertion

I'm not very comfortable with pointers in C and tried a piece of code to search a value in the linked list. Also, I made functions to insert at end(newNode_end), insert at the beginning(newNode_begin) and traverse.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
int data;
struct node* next;
}

void newNode_end(node **head,int data)
{
node* node_ptr, *temp;
node_ptr = (node* )malloc(sizeof(node));
node_ptr->data = data;
if((*head)==NULL)
{
    (*head) = node_ptr;
    node_ptr->next = NULL;
}
else
{
    temp = (*head);
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
        temp = temp->next;

    temp->next = node_ptr;
    node_ptr->next = NULL;
}
}

void newNode_begin(node **head,int data)
{
node* node_ptr, *temp;
node_ptr = (node* )malloc(sizeof(node));
node_ptr->data = data;
if((*head)==NULL)
{
    (*head) = node_ptr;
    node_ptr->next = NULL;
}
else
{
    node_ptr->next = (*head);
    (*head) = node_ptr;
}
}

void traverse(node *head)
{
node* temp;
if(head==NULL)
{
    printf("The list is empty\n");
}
else
{
    temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
}

int search_value(node **head,int value)
{
node* temp;
if((*head)==NULL)
{
    printf("The list is empty\n");
}
else
{
    temp = (*head);
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data==value)
        {
            printf("FOUND\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("NOT FOUND\n");
    return 0;
}
}


int main()
{
node *head = NULL;
int node_data,user_resp,value;
while(1)
{
    printf("----------MENU------------\n");
    printf("Press 1: ADD NODE IN THE BEGINNING\n");
    printf("Press 2: ADD NODE AT THE END\n");
    printf("Press 3: TRAVERSE THE LINKED LIST\n");
    printf("Press 4: SEARCH A VALUE\n");
    printf("Press 5: EXIT\n");
    scanf("%d",&user_resp);
    switch(user_resp)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Enter data for node\n");
        scanf("%d",&node_data);
        newNode_begin(&head,node_data);
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("Enter data for node\n");
        scanf("%d",&node_data);
        newNode_end(&head,node_data);
        break;

    case 3:
        traverse(head);
        break;

    case 4:
        printf("Enter value to be searched\n");
        scanf("%d",&value);
        search_value(&head,value);

    case 5:
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The insertion and traversal functions of the code works well but the search_value function sometimes crashes. Any guidance on the same would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you think your `traverse` and `search` function should be the same structure? Why are they different?

Comment: Search value returns 0 even if it succeeds

Comment: You don't need to pass pointer to head in search_value.

Comment: need `temp=temp->next;` at while-end. `if((*head)==NULL)` block also need return value;

Comment: As @BLUEPIXY says, in your search function, add `temp = temp->next;` at while-end, `if ((* head) == NULL)` will not do what you exepect, use `ìf (head == NULL)` will work, and `temp = (*head);` is incorrect too, `temp = head` will be better to assign a pointer.

Comment: I'm not using the returned value that was just to terminate the loop, so no worries I guess. @iwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the search function:

```
int search_value(node **head,int value)
{
node* temp;
if((*head)==NULL)
{
    printf("The list is empty\n");
}
else
{
    temp = (*head);
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data==value)
        {
            printf("FOUND\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("NOT FOUND\n");
    return 0;
}
}
```

In your while loop, you check if `temp != NULL` and initialize temp to `head`.  It seems like you want to actually traverse the list, and when `value` is found, you want to return.  However, you *never move to the next node*.

You simply check the value of `temp->data`, but unless the first node's data member equals `value`, the while loop is infinite.

In order to actually traverse the loop, it would be best to do something like:

```
temp = temp->next;
```

Comment: Oh yes! Got the mistake..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your search will really not work because in your while loop, you don't have code to change the value of the temp. you are only conditioning the head.
so in you code, add line of code: temp = temp->next; after the closing parenthesis of if statement.

```
int search_value(node **head,int value)
{
  node* temp;
  if((*head)==NULL)  
  {
    printf("The list is empty\n");
  }
else
{
  temp = (*head);
  while(temp!=NULL)
{
    if(temp->data==value)
    {
        printf("FOUND\n");
        return 0;
    }

     temp = temp->next;

}
printf("NOT FOUND\n");
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: and also, put some delay after you display the "Found" text, like you add
getch()
and wait for the user to input any character to go back to main menu.